# overload delete[] for array of pointers

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, destructor, delete-operator

I  search a method to overload operator of delete[] or suitable destructor for a code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class A {
private:
    string name;
public:
    A(string name){
        this->name=name;
    };
    ~A(){
        cout<<"Destructor. Destroyed "<<name<<"\n";
    };
    void operator delete(void* p, A* a){
        cout<<"-Delete "<<a->name<<"\n";
    };
    void operator delete(void* pointer){
        cout<<"Delete"<<"\n";
    };
    void operator delete[](void* pointer){
        cout<<"Delete[]"<<"\n";
    };
};

int main(){
int number = 5;
A** a = new A* [ number ];

delete [] a;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
};
```

But whatever I tried default delete[] is started each time from the file delete2.cpp. What do I do wrong?
[ADDED] Added an attempt to overload delete[].

Comment: You need to overload `operator delete[]`, too.

Comment: @Kerrek SB I tried :(

Comment: @Nawy We can't see your attempt.

Comment: You aren't ever allocating any As, only pointers to A.

Comment: @kfsone But default delete[] from delete2.cpp (that is started each time) looks like <code>void operator delete[]( void * p ){}<code>

Comment: @Nawy A::operator[] is only called for a pointer to a block of `A`s, not a pointer to a block of `A*`s. That's why it's calling your default, global, fallback, delete[] operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not creating or destroy instances of A, only pointers to it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class A {
private:
    string name;
public:
    A() {}
    A(string name){
        this->name=name;
    };
    ~A(){
        cout<<"Destructor. Destroyed "<<name<<"\n";
    };
    void operator delete(void* p, A* a){
        cout<<"-Delete "<<a->name<<"\n";
    };
    void operator delete(void* pointer){
        cout<<"Delete"<<"\n";
    };
    void operator delete[](void* pointer){
        cout<<"Delete[]"<<"\n";
    };
};

int main(){
int number = 5;
A* a = new A[ number ];

delete [] a;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
};
```

Calls operator[] as expected: http://ideone.com/EuS3Hi

Comment: Yes, its working. But You changed A** to A*. And I need exactly A**.

Comment: `operator[]` works on a type, not a pointer-to-type, so you would need to either (a) use an intermediate smart pointer e.g. std::unique_ptr, (b) create an APtr wrapper class around an A* pointer. Because your delete is not deleting a recognized type, it's falling through to your global `void operator delete[](void*)`, because that's where all delete[]s go for types that don't overload operator[], and the type `A*` doesn't overload operator[].

Comment: @kfdone Difficult... And without the use of clever pointers there is possibility to overload delete[] or to write a suitable destructor? Because in my source code the class A have a array of objects B, that I need to clean too, and for this purpose I need to be somehow wedged in the process of destroying A

Comment: @Nawy If you are `delete[]`ing array-of-pointer-to (A**) rather than array-of-instance-of (A*) there's no way to overload, nor will the destructors be invoked - raw-pointers are exactly that, they don't do anything smart, not even call the destructor of the object they point to.