# C++ overloaded delete operator for array of pointers not being called

Tags: c++, visual-c++

The delete operator is not being called. Any direction would be helpful. I am using Visual studio 2019. I did look at the link [overload delete[] for array of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37104018/overload-delete-for-array-of-pointers), but was not able to resolve my issue. Thank you for any help!

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <new>
// replacement of a minimal set of functions:
void* operator new(std::size_t sz) // no inline, required by [replacement.functions]/3
{
   std::printf("global op new called, size = %zu\n", sz);
   if (sz == 0)
      ++sz; // avoid std::malloc(0) which may return nullptr on success

   if (void* ptr = std::malloc(sz))
      return ptr;

   throw std::bad_alloc{}; // required by [new.delete.single]/3
}
void operator delete(void* ptr, size_t size) noexcept
{
   std::puts("global op delete called");
   std::printf("%d", size);
   std::free(ptr);
}
void operator delete[](void* ptr, size_t size) noexcept
{
   std::puts("global op delete called");
   std::printf("%d", size);
   std::free(ptr);
}
int main()
{
   unsigned char* p3 = new unsigned char[100]; 
   delete[] p3; // I was expecting this would call the overloaded delete operator
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you even able to overload the new and delete operators for non-user-defined types?

Comment: @NathanPierson You're not overriding them. You're replacing the global allocation and deallocation functions. See [`new.delete`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/new.delete).

Comment: Neat. For some reason I thought you could only do it with the member operators.

Comment: Try overriding `delete` without the size parameter.

Comment: Why are you using `printf` for your output instead of `std::cout`? Especially considering that you use the wrong format specifier for a `size_t` argument in your `delete` operators. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude -- the reason for using `printf` is that stream inserters are allowed to allocate memory, using `operator new`, and to free it with `operator delete`. If that happens, you risk an infinite recursion. `printf` doesn't know about the C++ memory management functions, so is safe to call from `operator new` and `operator delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not providing an overload for `operator new[](size_t sz)`, so you're lucky that your `operator new(size_t sz)` is being called at all.

The compiler is calling the unsized versions `delete[]`, so you need to provide a `operator delete[](void *ptr) noexcept` function. Note that [the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/new.delete) requires the non-size version to be replaced when replacing the version that takes a size.

Comment: It seems `operator new[]` calls `operator new` by default: http://eel.is/c++draft/new.delete#array-4

Comment: Thank you for responses, I completely missed the new[] operator. Also implemented the delete[] operator without the size and it works like a charm. My real issue is trying to troubleshoot an old application with memory allocation. Any idea how I could pass the size parameter, so that the freed up memory can be calculated.

Comment: you have to allocate additional memory (say 4/8 bytes) to store the size and use it when delete is called